# L.timeDimension sends time in the form of UTC to GeoServer not iso8601

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, postgis, geoserver

I really am stuck in the the using L.timedimension.

My geoserver asks the date in the following format from Psql:

```
  TO_TIMESTAMP(cast(cast(bc_issued_date as date) as varchar)|| '00:00:00' ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp as time 

 "2013-01-08 00:00:00"
 "2022-07-09 00:00:00"
 "2021-09-08 00:00:00"
```

Geoserver shows the layer correctly , but when I use L.timedimension nothing shows up. I checked the log and seems the time comes as UTC ash shown below:

```
 RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, STYLES=PolygonVariableThick, WIDTH=256, TIME=2012-   07-24T18:00:00.000Z, ENV=color:#808000, HEIGHT=256,    LAYERS=localhost:BuildingConset_TimeSlider_v1_2017, REQUEST=GetMap,    SRS=EPSG:4326,    BBOX=174.72656250000003,-36.597889133070204,175.078125,-36.3151251474805,       VERSION=1.1.0, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true, CQL_FILTER=1=1}
   RemoteOwsType = null
   RemoteOwsURL = null
   Request = GetMap
   RequestCharset = UTF-8
   ScaleMethod = null
   Sld = null
   SldBody = null
   SldVersion = null
   SortBy = null
   SortByArrays = null
   SRS = EPSG:4326
   StartIndex = null
   StyleBody = null
   StyleFormat = sld
   Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=PolygonVariableThick]]
   StyleUrl = null
   StyleVersion = null
   Tiled = false
   TilesOrigin = null
   *****Time = [Tue Jul 24 18:00:00 UTC 2012]*****
   Transparent = true
   ValidateSchema = false
   Version = 1.1.0
   ViewParams = null
   Width = 256
```

So, my question is that How can I force timedimension to send me the correct dateformat or how I can force GeoServer/Postgresql to convert the time?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>WMS example - Leaflet</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js">
</script><link href="Scripts2/Leaflet.TimeDimension-master/src/leaflet.timedimension.control.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #map {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 900px;
    }
</style>


 </head>
<body>

 <div id='map'></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setUTCHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [-36.924930, 174.853682],
    zoom: 10,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    timeDimension: true,
    timeDimensionControl: true,
    timeDimensionOptions: {
        //timeInterval: startDate.toISOString() + "/P1W",
        timeInterval: "2010-01-01/2018-02-02",
        period: "PT6H",
        currentTime: startDate.getTime()
    },
});

var testLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://xxx.yyy/geoserver/localhost/wms',
    {
       layers: 'localhost:BuildingConset_TimeSlider_v1_2017', format: 
  'image/png', transparent: true, opacity: 0.4, 
       version: '1.1.0', styles: 'PolygonVariableThick', env: 
 'color:#808000', CQL_FILTER: '1=1'//,time:2016
        , crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    }) 


var testTimeLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(testLayer, {
    updateTimeDimension: false,
});
testTimeLayer.addTo(map);
</script>
```

[image: TimeDimension]

Comment: TIME is a separate parameter not a CQL element, so I would put TIME=2010-01-01/2018-02-02 in your layer.

Comment: @IanTurton, sorry could you explain more please? what do you mean by ' in your layer', Are you talking about timedimension in GeoServer?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you have set up Geoserver correctly to use the time dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time (and elevation) are handled as special parameters in the WMS specification. So you need to use the `TIME` parameter rather than a CQL filter.